# Uncaught type error when I am using npm install popmotion(it is used for animation )

Tags: javascript, npm, typeerror, parcel, popmotion

No error was there when I used external js file link of popmotion provided by them but when I tried using parcel error occurred . After installing parcel I did npm install popmotion then I created localhost link but it didn't worked. There was an error in console log.
Error was:

```
Uncaught TypeError: (0 , _popmotion.styler) is not a function
    at Object.parcelRequire.animation.js.popmotion (animation.js:5)
    at newRequire (animation.7bfd2d21.js:47)
    at animation.7bfd2d21.js:81
    at animation.7bfd2d21.js:120
```

The js code is

```
import {styler, spring, listen, pointer, value } from "popmotion";

const ball = document.querySelector('.box');
const divStyler = styler(ball);
const ballXY = value({ x: 0, y: 0 }, divStyler.set);

listen(ball, 'mousedown touchstart')
  .start((e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    pointer(ballXY.get()).start(ballXY);
  });

listen(document, 'mouseup touchend')
  .start(() => {
    spring({
      from: ballXY.get(),
      velocity: ballXY.getVelocity(),
      to: { x: 0, y: 0 },
      stiffness: 200,
      // mass: 1,
      // damping: 10
    }).start(ballXY);
  });
```

and the html code is:

```
</!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Animation</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./animation.css">
</head>
<body>

        <h1>Animation</h1>
        <div class="box"></div>
    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./animation.js"></script>
</body>
```

Also when I just used external link for popmotion it worked fine. Below is working code.

The js code is:

```
const { styler, spring, listen, pointer, value } = window.popmotion;

const ball = document.querySelector('.box');
const divStyler = styler(ball);
const ballXY = value({ x: 0, y: 0 }, divStyler.set);

listen(ball, 'mousedown touchstart')
  .start((e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    pointer(ballXY.get()).start(ballXY);
  });

listen(document, 'mouseup touchend')
  .start(() => {
    spring({
      from: ballXY.get(),
      velocity: ballXY.getVelocity(),
      to: { x: 0, y: 0 },
      stiffness: 200,
      // mass: 1,
      // damping: 10
    }).start(ballXY);
  });
```

and the html code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Animation</title>
  <link href="./animation.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Animation</h1>
  <div class="box"></div>

  <script src="https://unpkg.com/popmotion@8.1.24/dist/popmotion.global.min.js"></script>
  <script src="./animation.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

popmotion site: https://popmotion.io/pure/

Note:This is my first Question and I am not sure if I have to provide any additional information. Please do let me know if you need additional info. Thanks.

- A Noob

Answer (score 0):

You use popmotion version 8 style. You can uninstall the current popmotion package and its dependencies (particularly styler) and then install poption v8. You can try popmotion v8.1.24